# How to add two columns from two different dataframes in R wherein one column just has subset of unique values of the other

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two dataframes, I need to add two columns from those two and store the result in the original bigger dataframe, but the bigger dataframe has lot more 'branch' column than the smaller one. I tried using match but the non matching branches the sum is NA

Sample code:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(branch = letters[seq(1,5)],
+                   rev = seq(10,50,10),
+                   stringsAsFactors = 0)
> df1
  branch rev
1      a  10
2      b  20
3      c  30
4      d  40
5      e  50
> 
> df2 <- data.frame(branch = c('b','d'),
+                   Amt = c(10,10),
+                   stringsAsFactors = 0)
> df2
  branch Amt
1      b  10
2      d  10
> 
> df1$rev + df2[match(df1$branch,df2$branch),2,drop = 1]
[1] NA 30 NA 50 NA
>
```

Expected Output

```
> df1
  branch rev
1      a  10
2      b  30
3      c  30
4      d  50
5      e  50
>
```

I tried using left join as below:

```
> left_join(df1, df2, by = 'branch')
  branch rev Amt
1      a  10  NA
2      b  20  10
3      c  30  NA
4      d  40  10
5      e  50  NA
> df1 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = 'branch')
> df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
> df1
  branch rev Amt
1      a  10   0
2      b  20  10
3      c  30   0
4      d  40  10
5      e  50   0
> df1$rev <- df1$rev + df1$Amt
> df1
  branch rev Amt
1      a  10   0
2      b  30  10
3      c  30   0
4      d  50  10
5      e  50   0
> df1$Amt <- NULL
> df1
  branch rev
1      a  10
2      b  30
3      c  30
4      d  50
5      e  50
>
```

Could someone let me know if there's a simpler solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would to store the output of `match` in a variable, `replace` `NA` to 0 and then add values

```
vals <- df2$Amt[match(df1$branch,df2$branch)]
df1$rev + replace(vals, is.na(vals), 0)
#[1] 10 30 30 50 50
```

---

Something similar in `dplyr`, doing `left_join` instead of `match`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'branch') %>%
  mutate(Amt = replace(Amt, is.na(Amt), 0), 
         rev  = rev + Amt) %>%
  select(names(df1))
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, rev :=
    setDT(df2)[.SD, on=.(branch), rev + nafill(Amt, fill=0)]
]
```

output:

```
   branch rev
1:      a  10
2:      b  30
3:      c  30
4:      d  50
5:      e  50
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this, no libraries required:

```
    df1 <- df1[order(df1$branch),] #sort based on branch
    df2 <- df2[order(df2$branch),] #sort also so next step works
    df1$branch[df1$branch %in% df2$branch] #just to check we are on correct path

    #do the task
    df1$rev[df1$branch %in% df2$branch] <- df1$rev[df1$branch %in% df2$branch]  + df2$Amt[df2$branch %in% df1$branch]
```

Warning -- if there are repeated "branch" values in df2...e.g. two "b", 
you would need to accumulate those before adding them to df1.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can aggregate both dataframes using `bind_rows` (and renaming Amt by rev in order to match colnames), group by "branch" and calculate the sum:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% bind_rows(., rename(df2, rev = Amt)) %>%
  group_by(branch) %>%
  summarise(rev = sum(rev))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  branch   rev
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a         10
2 b         30
3 c         30
4 d         50
5 e         50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `aggregate` to get the sum of rev in different branch group .

```
library(magrittr)
colnames(df2)[2] <- "rev"
df1 <- rbind(df1, df2) %>% aggregate(rev ~ branch, ., FUN = sum)
```